# Exclude a WordPress category from a function that auto-tags posts

Tags: wordpress

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction as to why this code works:

```
/* Auto-tag all posts w/Newsbreak tag to include in Newsbreak RSS feed */
function set_nbrk_tag_on_publish ($post_id, $post) {
    if ($post->post_type == 'post' && $post->post_status == 'publish') {
            wp_set_post_tags( $post_id, 'newsbreak', true );
        }
  }
add_action('save_post','set_nbrk_tag_on_publish',10, 2);
```

but this does not:

```
/* Auto-tag all posts w/Newsbreak tag (except Obits [-148]) to include in Newsbreak RSS feed */
function set_nbrk_tag_on_publish ($post_id, $post) {
    if ($post->post_type == 'post' && $post->post_status == 'publish' && $post->category__not_in == array( 148 ) ) {
            wp_set_post_tags( $post_id, 'newsbreak', true );
        }
  }
add_action('save_post','set_nbrk_tag_on_publish',10, 2);
```

I am not able to determine how to auto-tag but exclude a specific category or categories. Do I need a separate if statement for the categories? I have tried various combinations of

```
$post->category_in == -148
category_in == -148
category_in array(-148)
```

etc. Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do a `var_dump($post)` before your `if` statement. Make sure that the the `category__not_in` property actually exists.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am confused, I thought category__not_in was part of WP Query to get posts that are not in a specific category or categories? As in Is this not working because I am not actually executing a WP query in this function?

Comment: Yeah, you are not using WP Query. `save_post` is the action for a specific post. What you need to do is check to see if that post has that taxonomy assigned to it.

Comment: Yep, I want to make sure that the tag is NOT assigned to any posts that have the category ID 148, so I think the problem is with my syntax somewhere. Like, the && $post->category__not_in == array( 148

Comment: part is not working, but the rest of that line is.

Answer (score 0):

This does not use the WP_Query, so you don't have access to the `category__not_in` property on the `post` object.

You can try something like this instead (untested):

```
/* Auto-tag all posts w/Newsbreak tag (except Obits [-148]) to include in Newsbreak RSS feed */
function set_nbrk_tag_on_publish ($post_id, $post) {
    
    /* get the category term ids assigned to this post */
    $post_cats = wp_get_post_categories( $post_id, ['fields' => 'id' ] );
    
    if ($post->post_type == 'post' && $post->post_status == 'publish' &&  ! in_array( [148], $post_cats, FALSE ) ) {
        wp_set_post_tags( $post_id, 'newsbreak', true );
    }
}
add_action('save_post','set_nbrk_tag_on_publish',10, 2);
```

This basically checks to see if that term id is not in the array. If it's not, it will pass the conditional.

Comment: OK, so $post_cats is an array of all the categories and IDs, and then ! in_array( [148], $post_cats, FALSE ) ) is excluding anything with a category ID of 148. I am not much of a programmer and I am in way over my head here, but what is the FALSE part of that for?

Comment: The `FALSE` is to avoid a strict comparison of the the needle (your post id) and what's in the haystack (the post category array). And yeah, you basically want to stop anything from proceeding into the `if` statement if it has the category id. So you check if `148` is not in the array (that's the `!` in front of of the `in_array` - basically NOT in array, then proceed.

Comment: Thank you, I actually understand that now ;-) Only problem is it doesn't work, any post I create gets tagged as

Comment: 'newsbreak' even the ones for  which I set the category to obituaries (148).

Comment: As I said, I didn't test this. Do a `var_dump($post_cats)` and paste in the comments what you get back.

Comment: Ah, so basically the problem is that when you save the post, the post categories may not have been added yet, so you are testing too early. If you do the `var_dump($post_cats)` that might be empty.

Comment: Yeah, it's empty. Sorry, this forum is light years beyond my programming skills, which are virtually non-existent. I really appreciate your taking the time to assist me but I am going to sign off before I waste any more of your time.